# Не подключается js файл в html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

Не судите строго если проблема глупая.

Выучил основы JavaScript и продолжаю путь изучая React. Я почти всегда использую отдельно html и отдельно js файлы. Начав учить React, в туториале всегда js пишется в html файле, и нет инструкций как добавить js файл с Reactом в html.

Из базы js я знаю что подключается посредством добавления тега `<script src="index.js"></script>`. Узнал, что чтобы добавить React непосредственно в html, надо в head добавить скрипты с реактом, и написать `<script type="text/babel"`. Скрипт вписанный в html файле работает нормально, однако если я пишу скрипт в js файле и добавляю его в html файл, но ни в какую не работает. Не могу продвинуться в изучении React потому что не могу понять как это исправить.

Вариант (рабочий):

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
        <title>React Application</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>

        <script type="text/babel">
            const Func = () => {
                return <h1>Hello React</h1>;
            }

            ReactDOM.render(<Func />, document.getElementById("root"));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

================================================================

Вариант с js файлом (не рабочий):

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
        <title>React Application</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>

        <script src="script.js"> </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**script.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Func = () => {
    return <h1>Hello react</h1>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Func />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**Уточнение:** читал что может быть из-за стрелочных функций, однако если это и может быть проблемой, у меня не работает ни такой формат функции, ни с словом `function`

Comment: Попробуйте <script src="script.js" defer> </script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. У вас в JS скрипте используется JSX, поэтому в теге скрипт, нужно ставить
   `type="text/babel"`. Это нужно потому что вы компилируете JSX уже во время работы страницы, и бабелю нужно знать что именно компилять.
2. React и ReactDOM у вас прилетают через скрипты в хеде и доступны в глобальной области видимости, импорты не нужны тут.
3. Отметили в комментариях, что желательно поставить defer на теги со скриптами, чтобы быть увереным, что к моменту выполнения script.js React и ReactDOM будут доступны.
4. Подозреваю, что при всём этом не взлетит, будет cross-origin ошибка. В папке с этими файлами запустите `npx serve`, запустится сервер, в консоли будет адрес с вашим приложением. Чтобы заработало нужно чтоб на системе была nodejs и npm.

Так должен выглядеть index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
        <title>React Application</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>

        <script type="text/babel" src="script.js"> </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Так script.js

```js
const Func = () => {
    return <h1>Hello react</h1>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Func />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Node.js и nvm скачаны. По команде ```nvm --v``` выдает ```8.12.1```, ```node -v```  ---> ```v18.4.0```. Ваши рекомендации не сработали, но я не запускал npx serve. Сейчас еще посмотрю. И я так понимаю Вы имели ввиду npm server?

Comment: Имею в виду `npx serve`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve. Смотрите в консоль. Я опробовал решение, взлетело.

Comment: Да, это сработало, спасибо. Теперь каждый раз нужно будет запускать таким образом?

Comment: @Lcashe да, если раздельные файлы. Посмотрите программу курса, который изучаете. Дальше будет webpack/vite, там уже есть это всё из коробки :)